# How to create multiple Flux from aysnc callbacks

Tags: java, project-reactor

From Reactor's reference guide, I learnt that `Flux.create()` can be used to convert aysnc callback to `Flux`.

However, sometimes callbacks have multiple methods to receive multiple types of data, assume I have piece of code as below:

```
asrService.recognize(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void stateChange(State state) {
        // consume state
    }

    @Override
    public void onResultData(Result result) {
        // consume result
    }
});
```

How to convert it to two reactive streams: `Flux<State>` and `Flux<Result>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to use Some processors Like DirectProcessor you can create 2 Different Processors and on event emit item to processor and subscribe the processor but if you still want to use Flux.create you can do it like this

```
    Flux<Object> objectFlux;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    objectFlux = Flux.create(objectFluxSink ->
            asrService.recognize(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void stateChange(State state) {
                    objectFluxSink.next(state);
                }

                @Override
                public void onResultData(Result result) {
                    objectFluxSink.next(state);
                }
            }));





}

public Flux<Result> getResult(){
 return    objectFlux.filter(o -> o instanceof Result)
            .map(o -> ((Result)o));
}

public Flux<State> geState(){
    return    objectFlux.filter(o -> o instanceof State)
            .map(o -> ((State)o));
}
```

i still think that using processor should be much more cleaner and you dont need to do that filter and casting but you need to have 2 Processors 
Like this :

```
        DirectProcessor <Result> resultDirectProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();
    DirectProcessor<State> stateDirectProcessor = DirectProcessor.create();
    asrService.recognize(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void stateChange(State state) {
            stateDirectProcessor.onNext(state);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResultData(Result result) {
            resultDirectProcessor.onNext(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please give an example that using Processor?

Comment: @LiangChen yes i have eddied the answer

Comment: wouldn't registering two callbacks in two `Flux.create` work? This way each `Flux` would directly be of the correct type.

Comment: @SimonBaslé That's impossible, as the two callback methods are both in interface of `Callback`, there isn't a way to call `Flux.create` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just small snippet usable for given task.

```
Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
Sinks.EmitResult result = sink.tryEmitNext("some string");
```